# Ecto changeset - skip nil fields

Tags: ecto, elixir

How do I add a field to a `changeset` only if the field is not nil? I don't want to update the value in the database if the value is nil. I need to check 3 fields and only update the ones that are not nil.

current code:

```
  put "/products" do
    errors = {}
    IO.inspect(conn.body_params)

    product = Api.Product |> Api.Repo.get(conn.query_params["id"])
    IO.inspect(product)

    if conn.body_params["image"] do
      changeset = Api.Product.changeset(product, %{image: conn.body_params["image"]})
    end

    if conn.body_params["description"] do
      changeset = Api.Product.changeset(product, %{description: conn.body_params["description"]})
    end

    if conn.body_params["price"] do
      changeset = Api.Product.changeset(product, %{price: conn.body_params["price"]})
    end
    case Api.Repo.update(changeset) do
      {:ok, product} -> 
        errors = Tuple.append(errors, "Product updated")
      {:error, changeset} -> 
        errors = Tuple.append(errors, "Product not updated")
    end

    conn
      |> put_resp_content_type("application/json")
      |> send_resp(200, Poison.encode!(%{
          successs: "success",
          errors: Tuple.to_list(errors)
      }))
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new params map with only the keys which the schema accepts and whose value is not nil using `for`, and pass that to `changeset/2`:

```
product = Api.Product |> Api.Repo.get(conn.query_params["id"])
params = for key <- ~w(image description price), value = conn.body_params[key], into: %{}, do: {key, value}
changeset = Api.Product.changeset(product, params)
case Api.Repo.update(changeset) do
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what `validate_required/3` is for.
https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#validate_required/3

You pass it your changeset and a list of required fields as atoms. If any of the specified fields are not present (ie, `nil`), then an error will be added to your changeset and it will also be flagged as invalid.

```
iex> changeset |> validate_required([:field1, :field2, :field3])
%Ecto.Changeset{valid?: false, errors: %{"field1" => ["can't be blank"]}}
```

PS. you don't need to manage errors yourself as you're doing above. Errors will be automatically added to your changeset at `changeset.errors`.

Comment: I need them to be able to be nil during an insertion. Then I need to only update them here if they have values instead of nil. I need to make sure it doesn't cause an error if one of them is nil because the others that are not nil need to be saved.